# How can I new a xml file with python in SUMO?

Tags: python, xml, sumo

I'm new to [SUMO](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation_of_Urban_MObility_-_Wiki).And I can make `.nod.xml`、`.edge.xml` by hand.When I want to new random `flows`,there's lots of randomness to do, so I tried to use `sumolib` ,which is the SUMO python lib, but I still can't find orders to new a xml,modified a xml...So How does it work? Thx.

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you already created your network successfully and just need random traffic, try using randomTrips.py

```
randomTrips.py -n my.net.xml -o passenger.trips.xml --validate
```

It can also generate flows for easier editing, just add `--flows 1`.

In general you can edit all xml file swith a text editor of your choice but please be aware that for instance the .net.xml file should always be generated using netconvert or netedit.